# NSURLConnection and connectionDidFinishLoading sharing between multiple functions

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

This is a simplification, but I have an app that has the following methods:

```
//This is a common function that is used by various functions in my app to send a HTTP Post via NSURLConnection
- (void)sendPostWithURL:(NSString*)url

//This is the NSURLConnection function that has the response data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

//myFunction1: send a HTTP Post and receive response1.json
-(void)myFunction1{
 [self sendPostWithURL:@"http://www.somesite.com/response1.json"];
 }

//myFunction2: send a HTTP Post and receive response2.json
-(void)myFunction2{
 [self sendPostWithURL:@"http://www.somesite.com/response2.json"];
}
```

So as you can see, I have two functions (myFunction1 and myFunction2) that share a common NSURLConnection for sending and receiving data.

In the connectionDidFinishLoading() function, how can I tell whether the response is for myFunction1 or myFunction2?

I have one possibility, such as requesting that within the json response data, there is one key/value pair that allows me to see which response it is.  However, I have a feeling that there is a more elegant way for me to do this within the code itself.

Any advice would be great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling them "functions".  If you start thinking of them as "methods" in a class, a lot of this will make more sense.

You need to encapsulate all of the NSURLConnection stuff in a class (called, say, Downloader.m).
Downloader.m will have methods: sendPostWithUrl and connectionDidFinishLoading.

Then, when you need to download something, instantiate a new instance of downloader, and call it's sendPost method.  You will have a specific class instance for each download operation and those should be easy enough to keep track of.

Comment: Thank you, certainly great advice.  I ended up solving it by creating a custom wrapper around NSURLConnection with a tag property.  Using the tag, I was able to differentiate which response it was.  Thank you!